# Как переносить файлы через панель навигации Windows 10?

Tags: windows, windows-10

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Такое с любыми файлами в любое место. W2 (W:) это жёсткий диск. В системе администратор я, так что с правами проблем нет

Comment: А куда нибудь в документы или загрузки даст так перетащить?

Comment: Через панель навигации? Совсем никуда, даже в в папки на дисках.